# Can I get an .ascx file to compile in a class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I know this isn't possible; I'm looking for a workaround really. I have a bunch of classes in a **.dll** file that all inherit the same abstract `HtmlGenerator` class. All these do is generate content HTML for parts of the page, based on certain user settings. I also have `JavascriptGenerator` and `CssGenerator`, which do pretty much the same thing. Much like a `UserControl` ;)

All these controls are either rendered on the page or can be loaded via AJAX calls.

The problem I'm having is that the strings contain a lot of `"` and it's getting a bit ugly to put in strings. It'd be nice if I could get them into **.ascx** files.

I understand that **ascx** files can't be placed in a class library because the references to other files, such as images, aren't going to work. But all my files are generated HTML based on certain profile data. There aren't any images and there isn't any actions taking place, such as editing values in a database.

You can inherit `UserControl` and override the `Render` method in a class library, but is there a way of getting an **ascx** file to be compiled in a class library? Or is there a decent enough workaround? Perhaps I should put the HTML in the resources file?

Comment: Yes you can, but what version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: @James 2.0 on the server I think. Pretty old server but I've got VS2010 and I'm writing the site in .NET 3.5

Comment: @SLaks, I've seen Razor around a lot, but I've never looked into it before. I've avoided the need for it myself (until now it seems). Could you give me a couple of useful tips or links? Any quick pointers?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax

Comment: I've got both of them open already as they were the first two to come up in a google search for `Razor C#`, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice way of doing this myself, which I'll share with everyone. I do appreciate the answers though.

I changed my `HtmlGenerator` to an interface close to the following:

```
public interface IHtmlGenerator
{
    void Load(User user);
    void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer);
}
```

I then changed the code that reads the HTML as a string to make an `HtmlTextWriter` from a `StringWriter` object, which can be filled with the HTML using the `RenderControl` method.

It was quite simple really.. I added another web project, got all the `UserControl` classes to inherit `IHtmlGenerator`. UserControl already has a definition for `void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)`, so it was just a case of adding the `Load` method.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

1. Close VS.NET 2005.
2. Open the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Web\WebNewFileItems\CSharp` (assuming a default installation of VS.NET).
3. Open the CSharpItems.vsdir file in Notepad. Select the text and copy it to the clipboard.
4. Now open up the file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC#\CSharpProjectItems\CSharpItems.vsdir` and paste the contents of the clipboard underneath the existing text.
5. Now copy the contents of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Web\WebNewFileItems\CSharp` (excluding CSharpItems.vsdir) into the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC#\CSharpProjectItems`.

Here's a post from Scott Guthrie that might help too:
http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx

Comment: Sorry James, I don't really know what you're trying to get at here. What should this do?

Comment: It gives you access to web controls from a class library.

Comment: Might be slightly different for VS2010. That's why I asked what version of ASP.NET you were using. Should have asked what version of VS you were using, I suppose.

Comment: I did say I was using VS2010 ;) I'll give it a go anyway. I should be able to work out the differences

Answer (score 0):

I've created something for almost exactly this purpose. The project is named [EView](https://github.com/Earlz/EView) and it's hosted at GitHub under BSD license. The code is not the most readable (all stuffed into one T4 file to work with Mono as well as .Net), but it works for me in my website.

It uses T4 to create statically-compiled "views". So you just create a folder named "Templates" (or whatever), place the EViewGenerator.tt file in it and add HTML files (or whatever files you want). It will process them into a very simple to render C# plain-old-object. For example, you could place TestFile.html in it with this content:

```
{@ Title as string; @}
<html><head>
<title>{=Title=}</title>
<body>
Hey check out the dynamic title
</body>
</html>
```

and then when you go to render it as text, you just do something like:

```
var view=new TestFile();
view.Title="Some Title";
Response.Write(view.EViewRender()); //render returns a string
```

I created it to solve almost exactly the problem you describe so I figure maybe it'd be worth a look, even if it's not the most "complete" solution.

Some of the stuff that's not well documented includes foreach functionality:

```
Foreach test: <br />
{#
  var strings=new String[]{"Foo","Bar","Biz"};
#}
{!foreach s in strings!}
  s is equal to {=s=} <br />
{!end!}
```

and also "layouts" which are similar to MasterPages

MasterLayout.html:

```
{@
  Content as IEView;
  Comments as IEView;
  Title as string;
@}
<html>
<head><title>{=Title=}</title></head>
<body>

<div class="content">
  {= Content =}
</div>

<div class="comments">
  {= Comments =}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then an example piece of content.

MyContent.html:

```
{!layout MasterLayout!}
{!layout_field Content!}
This is some example content!
```

And to render:

```
var v=new MyContent();
v.Layout.Title = "My content";
v.Layout.Comments = new SomeCommentView();
Response.Write(v.EViewRender());
```

Comment: Looking pretty nice. Does seem very similar to razor though. One critical feature I need though; does it have some kind of foreach loop capability?

Comment: @Connell the documentation is a bit lacking(documentation is boring though! :) ) but I included an example of a foreach loop.